# Is there a cleaner way of getting individual regression estimates out from a multifactor model in R

Tags: r, regression, glm

I have solved what I want to get out of my code, I'm in search of a cleaner way of getting this result out? As in any built in functions, who I don't know about?

We have 2 correlated variables and a lot of binomial factors (around 200),
here illustrated with just f1 and f2:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
f1 <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
f2 <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)

# which gives the possible groups:
group <- rep(NA, 100)
group[which(f1 & f2)] <- "A"
group[which(!f1 & f2)] <- "B"
group[which(f1 & !f2)] <- "C"
group[which(!f1 & !f2)] <- "D"

df <- data.frame(group,y,x,f1,f2)
```

We run a model selection adding and removing terms and interactions and end up 
 with a model, here we say both f1 and f2 and their interactions with x
came out as predictors

```
m <- glm(y ~ x * f1 + x * f2)
```

Then my aim is to make a simple linear model output for each group i.e.:
y = a * x + b

```
# The possible groups:
groups <- data.frame(groups = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), f1=c(1,0,1,0), f2=c(1,1,0,0))

interactions <- grep(":", attr(m$terms, "term.labels"))
factors <- attr(m$terms, "term.labels")[-c(1,interactions)]
interaction.terms <- substring(attr(m$terms, "term.labels")[interactions], 3)

functions <- data.frame(groups$groups, intercept=NA, slope=NA)

for(i in seq(along=groups$groups)) {
  intercept <- coef(m)["(Intercept)"] + sum(groups[i, factors]*coef(m)[factors])
  slope <- coef(m)["x"] +  sum(groups[i, interaction.terms]*coef(m)[paste("x:", interaction.terms, sep="")])

  functions[i, "intercept"] <- intercept
  functions[i, "slope"] <- slope  
}
```

Which gives an output like this:

```
> functions
  groups.groups   intercept       slope
1             A -0.10932806 -0.07468630
2             B -0.37755949 -0.17769345
3             C  0.23635139  0.18406047
4             D -0.03188004  0.08105332
```

The output is the correct, and what I would like. So that is fine. I just think that this method is a quite complicated mess. I can't seem to find a cleaner way of getting these functions out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably recommend using `predict()` for this. The intercept is just the value a time `x=0`, and the slope is the difference in the values between `x=1` and `x=0`. So you can do

```
int <- predict(m, cbind(groups,x=0))
t1 <- predict(m, cbind(groups,x=1))

data.frame(group=groups$groups, int=int, slope=t1-int)
```

You didn't set a seed for your example so your exact results aren't reproducible, but if you do `set.seed(15)` before the sample generation, you should get

```
  group         int       slope
1     A -0.08372785 -0.16037708
2     B -0.03904330  0.14322623
3     C  0.16455660 -0.02951151
4     D  0.20924114  0.27409179
```

with both methods

Comment: This solution is incredebly much simpler and way less error prone!